# Is R+bigmemory package sufficient for column-oriented data management?

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a collection of financial time series of various sorts. Most of my analysis is either a column or a row oriented, very rarely I have to do any sort of complex queries. Also, I am (by now) doing almost all analysis in R.

Because of this, I am seriously considering not deploying any sort of RDBMS and instead managing data in R directly (saving RDS files). This would save me the pain of installing an administering a DB as well as probably improve the data loading speeds.

Is there any reason I should consider otherwise? Do you know anyone who manages their data this way? I know this is vague, but I am looking for opinions, not answers.

Answer (score 1):

If working in R is your comfort zone.. I'd keep your data management there as well, even if your analyses or runs are longer.

I've had a similar decision lately:

1. Should I go in the direction of learning and applying a new (language/dialect/system) to shave some milliseconds off execution time.

   or...
2. Should I go forth with the same stodgy old tools I have used, even if they will run slower at execution time?

Is the product of your runs for you only?  If so, I'd stick with data management in R only.. even if production runs are slower.

If you were designing something for a Bank, Cell Phone Service, or a similar transactional environment, I'd recommend finding the super solution.

But if your R production is for you.. I'd stay in R.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the opportunity cost. Learning a new language/ecosystem - and something like PostgreSQL surely qualifies - will soak up far more time than you likely think. Those skills may be valuable, but will they generate a return on time invested that is as high as the return you would get from additional time spent on your existing analysis?

If it's for personal use and there is no pressing performance issue, stick with R. Given that it's generally easier to do foolish things with text and RDS files than it is with a fully-fledged DB, just make sure you back up everything. From being a huge skeptic about cloud-based storage I have over the past half-year become a huge convert and all but my most sensitive information is now stored there. I use Dropbox, which maintains previous versions of data if you do mess up badly.

Being able to check a document or script from the cafe on the corner on your smartphone is nice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a column-by-column management package, `colbycol` in CRAN designed to provide DB-like functions for large datasets. I assume the author must have conducted the same sort of analysis.